# Android Studio emulator does not have internet

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, android-emulator

I have been using nox-Player for several months and I had no problem connecting to the Internet.

But since I installed **Android Studio emulators**, it connects to Wi-Fi, but it gives a **limited connection** message.

**The steps I have taken so far, but the problem has not been solved:**

1- Installing different versions of the emulator with different APIs

2- Deleting and reinstalling the emulator

3- Change system DNS settings

4- I use the latest version of Android Studio

I would be happy if any of my friends have encountered this problem before and were able to solve it, tell me their solution.

I will also post a picture of the problem

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try to run ping, ifconfig and traceroute6 from ADB?

Comment: Uninstall nox-Player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and here is how i fixed that..

1.Go the extended controls of the emulator by clicking three dots.

[image]

2. Then a Extended controls window will open, in that go to cellular and set meter status to temporary not metered.

[image]

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much . In disbelief, it was solved with your advice.